# Undefined Control Sequence \paragraph

Tags: beamer, undefined

I am trying to compile the following but I get this message:

```
! Undefined control sequence.
<argument> \paragraph
l.1290 \ttl@extract\paragraph
```

---

```
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% Beamer Presentation
% LaTeX Template
% Version 1.0 (10/11/12)
%
% This template has been downloaded from:
% http://www.LaTeXTemplates.com
%
% License:
% CC BY-NC-SA 3.0 (http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-nc-sa/3.0/)
%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   PACKAGES AND THEMES
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\documentclass[aspectratio=169]{beamer}


\mode<presentation> {

% The Beamer class comes with a number of default slide themes
% which change the colors and layouts of slides. Below this is a list
% of all the themes, uncomment each in turn to see what they look like.

%\usetheme{default}
%\usetheme{AnnArbor}
%\usetheme{Antibes}
%\usetheme{Bergen}
%\usetheme{Berkeley}
%\usetheme{Berlin}
%\usetheme{Boadilla}
%\usetheme{CambridgeUS}
%\usetheme{Copenhagen}
%\usetheme{Darmstadt}
\usetheme{Default}
%\usetheme{Dresden}
%\usetheme{Frankfurt}
%\usetheme{Goettingen}
%\usetheme{Hannover}
%\usetheme{Ilmenau}
%\usetheme{JuanLesPins}
%\usetheme{Luebeck}
%\usetheme{Madrid}
%\usetheme{Malmoe}
%\usetheme{Marburg}
%\usetheme{Montpellier}
%\usetheme{PaloAlto}
%\usetheme{Pittsburgh}
%\usetheme{Rochester}
%\usetheme{Singapore}
%\usetheme{Szeged}
%\usetheme{Warsaw}
%\usefonttheme{professionalfonts}
% As well as themes, the Beamer class has a number of color themes
% for any slide theme. Uncomment each of these in turn to see how it
% changes the colors of your current slide theme.

%\usecolortheme{albatross}
%\usecolortheme{beaver}
%\usecolortheme{beetle}
%\usecolortheme{crane}
%\usecolortheme{dolphin}
%\usecolortheme{dove}
%\usecolortheme{fly}
%\usecolortheme{lily}
%\usecolortheme{orchid}
%\usecolortheme{rose}
%\usecolortheme{seagull}
%\usecolortheme{seahorse}
%\usecolortheme{whale}
%\usecolortheme{wolverine}

%\setbeamertemplate{footline} % To remove the footer line in all slides uncomment this line
%\setbeamertemplate{footline}[page number] % To replace the footer line in all slides with a simple slide count uncomment this line

%\setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{} % To remove the navigation symbols from the bottom of all slides uncomment this line
}

\usepackage{graphicx} % Allows including images
\usepackage{booktabs} % Allows the use of \toprule, \midrule and \bottomrule in tables
%\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
%\usepackage{resizegather}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{adjustbox}
%\usepackage{systeme}
\usepackage{longtable}
%\usepackage{amsmath}
%\usepackage{beamerthemesplit}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{tikz}
\apptocmd{\frame}{}{\justifying}{} 
\setbeamersize{text margin left=0.9em}  % <- like this
\setbeamersize{text margin right=0.9em} % <- like this
\usepackage{tabularx}
%\usepackage{times}
%\usepackage{verbatim}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows,shapes}
\usepackage[percent]{overpic}
%\usepackage{callouts}
%\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
%\renewcommand{\familydefault}{\sfdefault}
%\usepackage{bookman}
\usepackage{mathptmx}
%\usepackage[scaled=0.9]{helvet}
%\usepackage{courier}
%\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
 
\usepackage{tgbonum}
\usepackage{chngpage}

\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usefonttheme{professionalfonts} % using non standard fonts for beamer
\usefonttheme{serif} % default family is serif
%\usetheme{Warsaw}
%\usepackage{fontspec}




\usepackage{setspace,graphicx,epstopdf,amsmath,amsfonts,amssymb,amsthm,versionPO}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{marginnote,datetime,enumitem,subfigure,rotating,fancyvrb}
\usepackage{hyperref}
%\usepackage[longnamesfirst]{natbib}
\usepackage{natbib}
\usepackage{mathtools, amssymb}
\usepackage{dblfloatfix}
\usepackage{adjustbox}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{caption} 
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\patchcmd{\thebibliography}{\section*}{\section}{}{}
\usepackage[section]{placeins}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{hhline}
\usepackage{fixltx2e}
\usepackage{authblk}
\usepackage[none]{hyphenat}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage[letterpaper,margin=1in]{geometry} % set suitable page size parameters
\usepackage{indentfirst} % Indent first sentence of a new section.
\usepackage{endnotes}    % Use endnotes instead of footnotes
\usepackage{jf}          % JF-specific formatting of sections, etc.
\usepackage[labelfont=bf,labelsep=period]{caption}   % Format figure captions
\usepackage{lmodern}

\definecolor{carnel}{rgb}{0.7, 0.11, 0.11}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\begin{table}                                             
\centering  
\caption{.  The table presents the results for the period of 2008-2014. Sub-Panels A1, A2 and A3 of the table show the result for sorting based on the coefficient of $GRI{X_{innov}}$ without controlling for the other two factors, with controlling for $DGRI{X_{innov}}$  and with controlling for both other factors, respectively. Sub-Panels B1, B2 and B3 show the same result for the case of sorting based on  $DGRI{X_{innov}}$ . Sub-Panels C1,C2 and C3 shows the same result for the case of sorting based on $UDGRI{X_{innov}}$.}                                                
\begin{tabular}{c c c c c c c c }                          
\hline                                                    
& & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 5-1 \\       
\hline                                                    
&Average Beta & -15.985 & -5.179 & -1.955 & 0.631 & 7.774 & 23.758 \\ 
                                                    
Sub-Panel A1&Average Returns & 1.468 & 1.218 & 1.412 & 1.542 & 1.673 & 0.205 \\     
                                                    
&Carhart Alpha & -0.464 & -0.356 & 0.062 & 0.297 & 0.325 & \bf{0.789} \\  
                                                    
&P-Value & 0.074 & 0.007 & 0.431 & 0.033 & 0.248 & 0.085 \\  
\hline                                                    
&Average Beta & -15.191 & -6.622 & -3.721 & -1.064 & 5.635 & 20.826 \\
                                                    
Sub-Panel A2&Average Returns & 1.175 & 1.269 & 1.302 & 1.770 & 1.639 & 0.463 \\     
                                                    
&Carhart Alpha & -0.594 & -0.200 & -0.030 & 0.393 & 0.077 & \bf{0.671} \\ 
                                                    
&P-Value & 0.005 & 0.170 & 0.719 & 0.006 & 0.753 & 0.053 \\   
\hline                                                    
&Average Beta & -13.003 & -4.918 & -2.341 & 0.225 & 8.390 & 21.392 \\ 
                                                    
Sub-Panel A3&Average Returns & 1.765 & 1.539 & 1.422 & 1.411 & 1.108 & -0.657 \\    
                                                    
&Carhart Alpha & 0.055 & 0.133 & 0.039 & 0.009 & -0.510 & -0.565 \\  
                                                    
&P-Value & 0.834 & 0.269 & 0.648 & 0.949 & 0.044 & 0.182 \\   
\hline                                                    
\end{tabular}                                             
                                               
\begin{tabular}{c c c c c c c c }                          
\hline                                                    
 & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 5-1 \\       
\hline                                                    
&Average Beta & -13.163 & -4.769 & -2.100 & 0.467 & 9.017 & 22.179 \\ 
                                                    
Sub-Panel B1&Average Returns & 1.670 & 1.393 & 1.274 & 1.354 & 1.666 & -0.004 \\    
                                                    
&Carhart Alpha & -0.251 & -0.160 & -0.074 & 0.094 & 0.318 & 0.569 \\ 
                                                    
&P-Value & 0.384 & 0.193 & 0.395 & 0.491 & 0.253 & 0.223 \\  
\hline                                                    
&Average Beta & -17.259 & -5.470 & -1.996 & 1.285 & 12.703 & 29.962 \\
                                                    
Sub-Panel B2&Average Returns & 1.498 & 1.559 & 1.247 & 1.419 & 1.241 & -0.257 \\    
                                                    
&Carhart Alpha & -0.255 & 0.093 & -0.095 & 0.068 & -0.328 & -0.073 \\
                                                    
&P-Value & 0.334 & 0.472 & 0.355 & 0.591 & 0.121 & 0.838 \\   
\hline                                                    
&Average Beta & -18.002 & -5.478 & -1.820 & 1.646 & 13.735 & 31.738 \\
                                                    
Sub-Panel B3&Average Returns & 1.400 & 1.490 & 1.281 & 1.474 & 1.420 & 0.020 \\     
                                                    
&Carhart Alpha & -0.377 & 0.013 & -0.042 & 0.132 & -0.143 & 0.235 \\ 
                                                    
&P-Value & 0.157 & 0.920 & 0.674 & 0.274 & 0.508 & 0.530 \\   
\hline                                                    
\end{tabular}                                             
                                             
\begin{tabular}{c c c c c c c c }                         
\hline                                                   
 & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 5-1 \\      
\hline                                                   
&Average Beta & -19.139 & -4.252 & 0.299 & 4.760 & 19.406 & 38.545 \\
                                                   
Sub-Panel C1&Average Returns & 1.507 & 1.212 & 1.370 & 1.594 & 1.712 & 0.205 \\    
                                                   
&Carhart Alpha & -0.439 & -0.349 & 0.019 & 0.335 & 0.373 & \bf{0.811} \\ 
                                                   
&P-Value & 0.105 & 0.006 & 0.820 & 0.015 & 0.191 & 0.085 \\ 
\hline                                                   
&Average Beta & -20.605 & -4.583 & 0.185 & 4.811 & 20.327 & 40.932 \\
                                                   
Sub-Panel C2&Average Returns & 1.126 & 1.295 & 1.260 & 1.699 & 1.886 & 0.759 \\    
                                                   
&Carhart Alpha & -0.485 & -0.129 & -0.121 & 0.304 & 0.211 & \bf{0.696} \\
                                                   
&P-Value & 0.048 & 0.377 & 0.141 & 0.027 & 0.381 & 0.061 \\  
\hline                                                   
&Average Beta & -18.894 & -4.015 & 0.431 & 4.746 & 19.126 & 38.020 \\
                                                   
Sub-Panel C3 &Average Returns & 1.104 & 1.305 & 1.399 & 1.640 & 1.796 & 0.692 \\    
                                                   
&Carhart Alpha & -0.519 & -0.111 & 0.020 & 0.245 & 0.112 & 0.630 \\ 
                                                   
&P-Value & 0.044 & 0.421 & 0.824 & 0.059 & 0.667 & 0.135 \\  
\hline                                                   
\end{tabular}                                            
\end{table} 
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Comment: `\paragraph` is a 4th level heading after section, subsection, subsubsection, it's not expected that you have a section hierarchy that deep in a presentation.

Comment: most of the packages you are loading make little sense in a beamer document, there is no automatic page breaking by default so longtable, placeins don't really have purpose, you specify mathptm to get times fonts then you load lmodern to get latin moderrn, tgbonum to get tex gyre, you can not have three different main document fonts???

Answer (score 4):

Your preamble made little sense in a beamer context and had multiple conflicting font packages and  packages loaded multiple times, it also used several packages related to sectioning that are not likely to work in a presentation. I could not run it as it used several files not in texlive.

However if I simply delete the entire preamble it works without error although with some warnings about over long lines.

Just add back packages *if* you need them.

```
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% Beamer Presentation
% LaTeX Template
% Version 1.0 (10/11/12)
%
% This template has been downloaded from:
% http://www.LaTeXTemplates.com
%
% License:
% CC BY-NC-SA 3.0 (http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-nc-sa/3.0/)
%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   PACKAGES AND THEMES
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\documentclass[aspectratio=169]{beamer}


\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\begin{table}                                             
\centering  
\caption{.  The table presents the results for the period of 2008-2014. Sub-Panels A1, A2 and A3 of the table show the result for sorting based on the coefficient of $GRI{X_{innov}}$ without controlling for the other two factors, with controlling for $DGRI{X_{innov}}$  and with controlling for both other factors, respectively. Sub-Panels B1, B2 and B3 show the same result for the case of sorting based on  $DGRI{X_{innov}}$ . Sub-Panels C1,C2 and C3 shows the same result for the case of sorting based on $UDGRI{X_{innov}}$.}                                                
\begin{tabular}{c c c c c c c c }                          
\hline                                                    
& & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 5-1 \\       
\hline                                                    
&Average Beta & -15.985 & -5.179 & -1.955 & 0.631 & 7.774 & 23.758 \\ 
                                                    
Sub-Panel A1&Average Returns & 1.468 & 1.218 & 1.412 & 1.542 & 1.673 & 0.205 \\     
                                                    
&Carhart Alpha & -0.464 & -0.356 & 0.062 & 0.297 & 0.325 & \bf{0.789} \\  
                                                    
&P-Value & 0.074 & 0.007 & 0.431 & 0.033 & 0.248 & 0.085 \\  
\hline                                                    
&Average Beta & -15.191 & -6.622 & -3.721 & -1.064 & 5.635 & 20.826 \\
                                                    
Sub-Panel A2&Average Returns & 1.175 & 1.269 & 1.302 & 1.770 & 1.639 & 0.463 \\     
                                                    
&Carhart Alpha & -0.594 & -0.200 & -0.030 & 0.393 & 0.077 & \bf{0.671} \\ 
                                                    
&P-Value & 0.005 & 0.170 & 0.719 & 0.006 & 0.753 & 0.053 \\   
\hline                                                    
&Average Beta & -13.003 & -4.918 & -2.341 & 0.225 & 8.390 & 21.392 \\ 
                                                    
Sub-Panel A3&Average Returns & 1.765 & 1.539 & 1.422 & 1.411 & 1.108 & -0.657 \\    
                                                    
&Carhart Alpha & 0.055 & 0.133 & 0.039 & 0.009 & -0.510 & -0.565 \\  
                                                    
&P-Value & 0.834 & 0.269 & 0.648 & 0.949 & 0.044 & 0.182 \\   
\hline                                                    
\end{tabular}                                             
                                               
\begin{tabular}{c c c c c c c c }                          
\hline                                                    
 & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 5-1 \\       
\hline                                                    
&Average Beta & -13.163 & -4.769 & -2.100 & 0.467 & 9.017 & 22.179 \\ 
                                                    
Sub-Panel B1&Average Returns & 1.670 & 1.393 & 1.274 & 1.354 & 1.666 & -0.004 \\    
                                                    
&Carhart Alpha & -0.251 & -0.160 & -0.074 & 0.094 & 0.318 & 0.569 \\ 
                                                    
&P-Value & 0.384 & 0.193 & 0.395 & 0.491 & 0.253 & 0.223 \\  
\hline                                                    
&Average Beta & -17.259 & -5.470 & -1.996 & 1.285 & 12.703 & 29.962 \\
                                                    
Sub-Panel B2&Average Returns & 1.498 & 1.559 & 1.247 & 1.419 & 1.241 & -0.257 \\    
                                                    
&Carhart Alpha & -0.255 & 0.093 & -0.095 & 0.068 & -0.328 & -0.073 \\
                                                    
&P-Value & 0.334 & 0.472 & 0.355 & 0.591 & 0.121 & 0.838 \\   
\hline                                                    
&Average Beta & -18.002 & -5.478 & -1.820 & 1.646 & 13.735 & 31.738 \\
                                                    
Sub-Panel B3&Average Returns & 1.400 & 1.490 & 1.281 & 1.474 & 1.420 & 0.020 \\     
                                                    
&Carhart Alpha & -0.377 & 0.013 & -0.042 & 0.132 & -0.143 & 0.235 \\ 
                                                    
&P-Value & 0.157 & 0.920 & 0.674 & 0.274 & 0.508 & 0.530 \\   
\hline                                                    
\end{tabular}                                             
                                             
\begin{tabular}{c c c c c c c c }                         
\hline                                                   
 & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 5-1 \\      
\hline                                                   
&Average Beta & -19.139 & -4.252 & 0.299 & 4.760 & 19.406 & 38.545 \\
                                                   
Sub-Panel C1&Average Returns & 1.507 & 1.212 & 1.370 & 1.594 & 1.712 & 0.205 \\    
                                                   
&Carhart Alpha & -0.439 & -0.349 & 0.019 & 0.335 & 0.373 & \bf{0.811} \\ 
                                                   
&P-Value & 0.105 & 0.006 & 0.820 & 0.015 & 0.191 & 0.085 \\ 
\hline                                                   
&Average Beta & -20.605 & -4.583 & 0.185 & 4.811 & 20.327 & 40.932 \\
                                                   
Sub-Panel C2&Average Returns & 1.126 & 1.295 & 1.260 & 1.699 & 1.886 & 0.759 \\    
                                                   
&Carhart Alpha & -0.485 & -0.129 & -0.121 & 0.304 & 0.211 & \bf{0.696} \\
                                                   
&P-Value & 0.048 & 0.377 & 0.141 & 0.027 & 0.381 & 0.061 \\  
\hline                                                   
&Average Beta & -18.894 & -4.015 & 0.431 & 4.746 & 19.126 & 38.020 \\
                                                   
Sub-Panel C3 &Average Returns & 1.104 & 1.305 & 1.399 & 1.640 & 1.796 & 0.692 \\    
                                                   
&Carhart Alpha & -0.519 & -0.111 & 0.020 & 0.245 & 0.112 & 0.630 \\ 
                                                   
&P-Value & 0.044 & 0.421 & 0.824 & 0.059 & 0.667 & 0.135 \\  
\hline                                                   
\end{tabular}                                            
\end{table} 
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```